# field of definition of isogenies of abelian varieties

Tags: abelian-varieties, ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $A$ be an abelian variety over a field $k$, and let $N$ be a finite subgroup of $A$.  Suppose that $N$ is also defined over $k$, or at least that all Galois automorphisms fixing $k$ leave $N$ invariant.  Then I've heard it stated that there is an abelian variety $B / k$ and an isogeny $\phi: A \rightarrow B$ with kernel $N$, such that $\phi$ is defined over $k$.  I can't seem to find this stated anywhere (except in Silverman, where it is stated for elliptic curves as an exercise) and am not sure how to prove it.  Does anyone know how to prove this and/or where to cite it in the literature?

Comment: Isn't this in Weil?

Comment: Do you mean, in his "varietes abeliennes" book?

Comment: This is in Mumford's book on Abelian Varieties (for a finite subgroup scheme). Mumford assumes that the ground field is algebraically closed, but the proof doesn't need this. Alternatively, if you are willing to assume that the ground field is perfect, then the statement follows from the algebraically closed case + descent.

Comment: Choose $n > 0$ killing $N$, so $N \subset A[n]$. By fppf descent theory, the finite fppf map $[n]:A \rightarrow A$ identifies the target as the quotient $A/A[n]$.  So the source is an fppf $A[n]$-torsor over the target. Using the torsor viewpoint (and so more descent theory), we can work *Zariski-locally* on the target to form the quotient $B$ of this torsor by $N$ using just *affine* considerations. This quotient is then seen to be what we sought. A merit of this argument (over the one in Mumford's book) is that it works with abelian schemes over *any* base scheme; no projectivity hypotheses.