# Defining abstract varieties and their morphisms over a finitely generated subfield of the base field

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, arithmetic-geometry, schemes, limits-and-colimits

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field.
By a finitely generated subfield of $k$ I mean a subfield $k_0\subset k$ that is finitely generated over the prime subfield of $k$ (that is, over $\mathbb Q$ or $\mathbb F_p$).

I need a reference or a proof for the following (well-known? evident?) proposition:

> **Proposition.**
>   *Let
>   $$f\colon X\to V$$
>   be a morphism of $k$-varieties.
>   Then the triple  $(X,Y,f)$ can be defined over a finitely generated subfield of $k$.
>   In other words, there exists a finitely generated subfield $k_0\subset k$
>   and a morphism of $k_0$-varieties
>   $$f_0\colon X_0\to Y_0$$
>   such that
>   $(X_0,Y_0,f_0)\times_{k_0} k$ is isomorphic to $(X,Y,f)$.*

A referee asked me to prove this assertion. I know how to prove this for affine and projective varieties, but not for *abstract* varieties.

Comment: In the case you need it, you may also be interested by this question and its answers https://mathoverflow.net/questions/211867/field-of-definition-of-dominant-morphisms

Comment: This is the notion of "spreading out", discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1895568).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is treated (in much greater generality) in EGA IV$_3$, **Théorème 8.8.2**. The existence of $X_0$ and $Y_0$ follows from part (ii), whereas the existence of $f_0$ is part (i).

**References.**

[EGA IV$_3$]  A. Grothendieck, [*Éléments de géométrie algébrique. IV: Étude locale des schémas et des morphismes de schémas. (Troisième partie)*](http://www.numdam.org/articles/PMIHES_1966__28__5_0). Publ. Math., Inst. Hautes Étud. Sci. **28**, 1-255 (1966). [ZBL0144.19904](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0144.19904). DOI: [10.1007/BF02684343](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02684343)

Comment: If one prefers English, it is also in [Görtz-Wedhorn], Chapter 10, "Schemes over inductive limits of rings".

Answer (score 10):

A variety $V$ is a finite union of open affine varieties $V_i$, and because $V$ is separated (usually part of the definition of variety) the intersections $V_i\cap V_j$ are also affine. Now $V$ can be reconstructed from the affine varieties $V_i,V_i\cap V_j$ and the maps of affine varieties $V_i\cap V_j\to V_i$. Obviously, this system is defined over a finitely generated field.
Hence $X$ and $V$ are defined over a finitely generated field. The graph of $f$ is a closed subvariety of $X\times V$, and so is defined by a coherent sheaf of ideals in the structure sheaf of $X\times V$, which is obviously defined over a finitely generated field.

Comment: Thank you, @anon! I have included your proof in my paper with a reference to "anonymous Mathoverflow user".

Comment: Ex ungue leonem!

Comment: Dear Mikhail: and who might this modern Newton be?